# Automating API SDK testing that supports multiple programming languages

Tags: testing, automation, sdk, frameworks

I have a requirement to automate testing for an API SDK written in 5 programming languages.
The SDK is similar to jira SDKs.
Writing Tests across all 7 languages will lead to duplicating testing logic in all programming languages.

I want to find a way to call the SDK methods (which are basically API calls internally) from different programming languages in any one language (preferably python) and compare the response with the public api call (SDKs being wrappers for these public APIs.)
So far I have thought of creating a rest server in all languages (wrapper APIs over the SDK methods) and call these wrapper APIs to get the response and then proceed with comparison

I am wondering how the industry soles this problem in general and if there is a simpler solution to this problem which does not involve creating wrapper APIs for SDKs from different languages.

Comment: Curious, what approach did you take finally? We had a similar requirement, and stalled testing for the time being

Comment: Can you please share the solution if you find any perfect solution? I have the same scenario and looking for the best and most simple approach.

Comment: Tried a hacky solution to call the sdk methods by encapsulating all sdks in a backend server and trigger bash scripts to call the sdk methods in different language. In tests it was just a rest api call with request to trigger a particular SDK and methods inside . Adding tests to it was difficult and maintaining it was also a challenge.
we realised at the end, sdk methods were just api calls. All we needed to test from the individual sdk was to see if the individual api call was made properly with request, header and params passed properly. We ended up relying on unit tests for that.